# MYSQL database server Optimize: Queries very slow with many connections

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am running a MySQL DB server. During load test, with thousands of connections, MySQL queries are taking time in minutes. What can I do to optimize this situation?

Here is the brief description of my mysql db configuration

1. Only read access to tables.
2. Using Innodb engine
3. Have run mysqltuner, and implemented its recomendation
4. The system is under lot of queries and probably half open connections too.
5. Have done file system optimizations.

I realize it is very open ended question, but would like any inputs .

EDIT: Adding more info:

Queries are very simple like "select * from q6 where created_at='2013-10-02+00:00:00'".
Queries will always of this form only. Just too many of them.
 Table has schema like(one of the six huge tables) :
create table q4t_table (
created_at TIMESTAMP, 
tweet TEXT) engine=InnoDB;

The tables are indexed on timestamp(or userid which is int in some tables).
At one time, only one table out of six will be accessed.

Table size is typicall 300Mb or 3Gb or 8Gb.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to help identify potential optimizations.  What queries are long running and why?  Are your queries in a wait state for some reason?  Are you running up against max connection limits?  Do you have appropriate indexed for slow queries? Do you have appropriate memory allocation for the indexes? Is the server properly sized to handle your load?

Comment: @MikeBrant I added more info to the question.
 Idk how to get information about query state. But I tried accessing my db when server was under test. A simple count on table took more than 2 minutes.

How to change memory allocation for indexes? I think i could be running against max number of connections too.

Comment: For the one `CREATE TABLE` example you gave, is that the complete table schema?  If so than you have no indexes on that tables and will clearly have non-optimized queries, which on a large table could make you queries take a LONG time to run.  It seems that you need read up on proper indexing in MySQL.

Comment: I indexed the tables later. So the table is indexed.

Comment: It might help to show output from show processlist command in your question from a point in time where you see bad query performance. You should also add table definitions for tables related to queries in processlist which show long running times.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

You're likely running out of memory with so many open connections. You should be using connection pooling like sqlRelay or the pooling mechanism built into your language platform.